# UIView disappears after calling UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have two subviews in my view controller, both embedded in a UIScrollview. One of them is a subclass of UIView and the other created in interface builder with buttons etc in it, but also referenced by my view controller...

I use a share button to call UIActivityViewController which works fine. Only problem is when I tap on Facebook/Twitter and share an image(which works fine) - it goes away but when I return the UIView I created in IB is not visible, nor any of its buttons/elements etc.

I did an nslog in the completion handler for the UIActivity and it still exists, not hidden, and a count of all its subviews returns 19. Also check its frame which is fine so I have no idea why its not showing.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
NSString *textToPost = @"Text to post";
UIImage *anImage = [self.player imageOfView];
NSArray *activityItems = @[textToPost, anImage];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint];


[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    NSLog(@"input view status %i/n number of subviews%i", self.inputView.hidden, [self.inputView.subviews count]);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.inputView.frame));


}];
```

output:

input view status 0/n number of subviews19
{{0, 0}, {320, 438}}

Answer (score 0):

well if all are there then may be subview hides by some other view so try with `bringSubviewToFront`: it may be helps you.

```
    [yourview bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
```